# open('*.json') gives "UnicodeDecodeError"

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-3.8, python-unicode

I'm trying to import a .json file as a dictionary using the following code:

```
import json

with open('StreamingHistory0.json') as json_file: 
    history = json.load(json_file)
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 97181: character maps to <undefined>
```

What is the cause of this error and is there any suitable fix for it?

Comment: Did you tried `open('StreamingHistory0.json', encoding='utf-8')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably an encoding error. Try

```
with open('StreamingHistory0.json', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: isn't `'utf-8'` the default?

Comment: *"restart PC type problem"* sound like Windows ;-) Seriously, seems I'm mistaken, [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) say *" if encoding is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: locale.getpreferredencoding(False)"*. So on Windows, this can be cp1252 - which seems to be the cause why the OP is experiencing this error.